# "Cannot read property 'issues' of undefined" Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, es6-promise, use-effect, use-state, gitlab-api

I am using gitbeaker to get a project from gitlab API, after fetching the project, I used useState to save the project object, now I want to fetch another API whose URL is in that object, but whenever I try to access that URL, an error appears "Cannot read property 'issues' of undefined".
Here's my code:

```
const [project, setProject] = useState<any>({});
  const api = new Gitlab({
    host: "https://example.com",
    token: "my token",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const projectsPromises = await api.Projects.all().then((allprojects) => {
        return allprojects;
      });

      Promise.all(projectsPromises).then((data) => {
        setProject(data.find((element) => element.id === 338));
      });
    })();

    return () => {};
  }, []);

  console.log(project);
  console.log(project._links.issues);
  fetch(project._links.issues).then((res) => console.log(res));
```

console.log(project); gives me {} and after some time it prints the object, that's why when I try to use project._links.issues it is undefined as I think it isn't resolved yet but I don't know how to make it work.

**I solved it by** fetching the data in the useEffect hook and saving the response of the api in the state so that I can access it later in my code, like that

```
const [issues, setIssues] = useState<any>([]);
```

```
 Promise.all(projectsPromises).then((data) => {
        const celoProject: any = data.find((element) => element.id === 338);
        setProject(celoProject);
        const projectIssues = fetch(celoProject._links.issues)
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((allIssues) => {
            setIssues(allIssues);
          });
      });
```

If someone has a better way or an explanation why I couldn't access it outside the useEffect, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Anything inside the `useEffect` hook will only execute when the page first loads (because you provided an empty array as the second argument). Anything outside of it will execute on every render (every time props or state changes). That is why it logs `{}` the first time because the effect is asynchronous and hasn't completed before the component is rendered.

You should run the second fetch in the `useEffect` hook after the first API request completes. Need more information to determine what exactly is happening beyond this.

```
const [project, setProject] = useState<any>({});
const api = new Gitlab({
  host: "https://example.com",
  token: "my token",
});

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    const projectsPromises = await api.Projects.all().then((allprojects) => {
      return allprojects;
    });

    Promise.all(projectsPromises).then((data) => {
      const projectResponse = data.find((element) => element.id === 338)
      setProject(projectResponse)
      fetch(projectResponse._links.issues).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
        // Do something with this response
      });
    });
  })();

  return () => {};
}, []);

console.log(project);
console.log(project._links.issues);
```

Comment: it gives me that error "(TypeError): Cannot read property 'issues' of undefined" and then the response.

Comment: Sounds like _links does not exist on the `project` object, what does the object look like?

Comment: it exists, here it is:
 _links:
events: "https://....../api/v4/projects/338/events"
issues: "https://....../api/v4/projects/338/issues"

Comment: oops i named the const variable the same as the state. Updated code. Changed to `projectResponse`

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work, the error is "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'issues' of undefined"

Comment: Need more info, you say it's defined but the computer says it's not, so need more info.

Comment: when I print project first it gives me {} then after some time it prints the object but project._links.issues always gives the error of undefined

Comment: Thank you for your time and your comment, it helped me to figure out the solution!

Comment: Added some more info about async and component rendering that should help.